# Trouble downloading tensorflow with incorrect version

Tags: linux

Long stacktrace when I try to import tensorflow after downloading. Here was my downloading command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Then I open python and import tensorflow and get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.23' not found (required by /home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.23' not found (required by /home/dave/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I believe I don't have the correct version, but I am not 100% sure how to download it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I needed to simply run the command

> conda install tensorflow